# Certbot, Apache, Django - Current configuration does not support automated redirection

Tags: django, apache, ssl-certificate, certbot

I want to add ssl certificate for my domain, let's call it "domain.net"

I have VPS on Bluehost, Django on Apache and wanted to add certificate using Certbot.

During the installation, I got these messages:

> Deploying certificate Successfully deployed certificate for domain.net
> to /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf Successfully deployed certificate for
> [www.domain.net](http://www.domain.net) to /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf Failed redirect for
> domain.net Unable to set the redirect enhancement for domain.net.
>
> NEXT STEPS:
>
> - The certificate was saved, but could not be installed (installer: apache). After fixing the error shown below, try installing it again
>   by running:   certbot install --cert-name domain.net
>
> Unable to find corresponding HTTP vhost; Unable to create one as
> intended addresses conflict; Current configuration does not support
> automated redirection Ask for help or search for solutions at
> https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile
> /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for
> more details.

How to solve this error?

Not sure if that will help but here is a 'apachectl -S' out

```
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:80           is a NameVirtualHost
         default server server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:300)
         port 80 namevhost server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:300)
         port 80 namevhost proxy-subdomains-vhost.localhost (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:663)
                 wild alias cpanel.*
                 wild alias whm.*
                 wild alias webmail.*
                 wild alias webdisk.*
                 wild alias cpcalendars.*
                 wild alias cpcontacts.*
127.0.0.1:443          is a NameVirtualHost
         default server server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:771)
         port 443 namevhost server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:771)
                 wild alias cpanel.*
                 wild alias whm.*
                 wild alias webmail.*
                 wild alias webdisk.*
                 wild alias cpcalendars.*
                 wild alias cpcontacts.*
         port 443 namevhost server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:913)
162.241.177.72:80      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:321)
         port 80 namevhost server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:321)
         port 80 namevhost domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:382)
                 alias mail.domain.com
                 alias www.domain.com
         port 80 namevhost domain.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:463)
                 alias mail.domain.net
                 alias domain.net
                 alias www.domain.net
                 alias www.domain.domain.com
         port 80 namevhost proxy-subdomains-vhost.localhost (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:663)
                 wild alias cpanel.*
                 wild alias whm.*
                 wild alias webmail.*
                 wild alias webdisk.*
                 wild alias cpcalendars.*
                 wild alias cpcontacts.*
162.241.177.72:443     is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:530)
         port 443 namevhost domain.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:530)
                 alias mail.domain.net
                 alias domain.net
                 alias www.domain.net
                 alias www.domain.domain.com
                 alias cpcalendars.domain.net
                 alias webdisk.domain.net
                 alias cpcontacts.domain.net
                 alias cpanel.domain.net
                 alias webmail.domain.net
         port 443 namevhost server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:771)
                 wild alias cpanel.*
                 wild alias whm.*
                 wild alias webmail.*
                 wild alias webdisk.*
                 wild alias cpcalendars.*
                 wild alias cpcontacts.*
         port 443 namevhost server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:913)
*:*                    server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:351)
*:443                  server.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:913)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/etc/apache2/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/apache2/logs/error_log"
Mutex rewrite-map: dir="/run/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: dir="/run/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: MODSEC_2.5
Define: MODSEC_2.9
User: name="nobody" id=99
Group: name="nobody" id=99
```